How can I use MetaDataExtractor and XmpCore to add keywords to the XMP data in an image
I would like to update/add keywords to the XMP data in image files, mostly JPEGs. I can see how to extract and view the data, but not how to update it. I'm using MetadataExtractor and XmpCore, by Drew Noakes.
I am a complete newbie to image meta data, so excuse my ignorance.

MetadataExtractor doesn't support writing any metadata to files. It only supports extraction of metadata.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883854/updating-image-xmp-data-via-xmp-core-dotnet
